# Use htaccess and PHP Sessions to restrict direct access to swf files

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have several flash presentations, which I would like to restrict access to only logged in users. I have a log in form that sets a session variable for each presentation that indicates if the logged in user has access to that particular presentation.

```
// User's access is stored in DB with other account info, and sessions are set when logged in
$_SESSION['mfg'] = 'yes';
$_SESSION['product'] = 'no';
```

In this case the user should be able to access the 'mfg' presentation, but not the 'product' presentation.

Cookies are also set as follows:

```
setcookie('mfg', $_SESSION['mfg'],  time() + (60 * 60 * 24 * 7));
setcookie('product', $_SESSION['product'],  time() + (60 * 60 * 24 * 7));
```

This works great for direct access to the presentation, as I set an index file in the /mfg/ directory for example to check if $_SESSION['mfg'] is set to 'yes'. If it is, the presentation loads, if not the user gets redirected elsewhere.

**The Problem**

Regardless of whether or not someone is logged in and the session/cookie is set to 'yes', if they visit /mfg/swf/slide1.swf directly they can view the slide in their browser. They can then cycle through the presentation by visiting /mfg/swf/slide2.swf, etc...

I would like to somehow use an .htaccess file in the /mfg/swf/ folder to check if $_SESSION['mfg'] (or the cookie 'mfg'??) is set to 'yes'. If it is, then it should allow the person to view the slides, if not then they should be redirected to the log in form (/login.php).

**The Bigger Problem**

I don't really know how to write an htaccess file. I only know that this is a possibility from a few searches that sounded like they were written in another language.

Comment: put the files outside the root directory and serve them through a script

Comment: Why do you need htaccess for this? Shouldn't you do the checking in your script? Also with the example above unless you are using session_id then more then likely you are still using cookies, depending on your php.ini setup

Comment: @LiamSorsby My script does the checking, and it works fine when the user goes about the normal course of viewing the presentation - they log in, they are given link(s) to click to view the presentation(s) depending on the presentations they have access to, then they view the presentation with no issue. However anyone could visit http://example.com/mfg/swf/slide1.swf, ...slide2.swf, etc. as the individual slide files have no way (that I know of) to check to see if a cookie is set or not, and what that cookie's value is. I'd like to use htaccess to prevent direct accessing of the swf slide files

Comment: Sorry i understand now, i think @Dagon has given the best option. If it is an option, otherwise try something like what is suggested on http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/smarter-way-to-prevent-image-hotlinking-with-htaccess/

Comment: I have tried moving them like Dagon suggested, however when I do that, and updated the script to retrieve these files from /home/httpd/vhosts/example.com/private/swf/ rather than from example.com/mfg/swf/, the slides don't display in the presentation mode (the intended way for users to view the slides). It solves the issue of not being able to directly link to the slide files, but also won't display as intended. @LiamSorsby hotlink suggestion would only prevent someone from including the individual slides on their site, but wouldn't prevent directly visiting the individual slide URLs correct?

Comment: yes thats correct, why don't you try <FilesMatch "\.swf$">
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

Comment: @LiamSorsby this also doesn't display the slides in the presentation mode.